# Creating multiple framesets, vertical and horizontal. (HTML, CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

currently I have a horizontal frameset at the top of my page for my header and then a frame under that as the main body of my webpage. all my pages load within the main body. 
I am trying to add two vertical frames to either side of my webpage. Here is my currently HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <frameset border="0" frameborder="0" rows="10%, 90%">
      <frame src="header.html" name="header" noresize="noresize"> </frame>
      <frame src="home.html" name="main" noresize="noresize"> </frame>
  </frameset><noframes></noframes>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="0" cols="7%, 86%, 7%">
 <frame src="left.html" noresize="noresize"> </frame>
 <frame src="home.html" noresize="noresize"> </frame>
 <frame src="right.html" noresize="noresize"></frame>
</frameset>
  </html>

<-------------------------------------------------->
|                            Header                |
<-------------------------------------------------->
|  |                                           |   |
|  |                                           |   |                                                  |  |                                           |   |
|  |                                           |   |
|  |                       Body                |   |
|  |                                           |   |
|  |                                           |   |                                                  |  |                                           |   |
|  |                                           |   |
|  |                                           |   |
<-------------------------------------------------->
```

The top frame set and is loaded and the bottom is not. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT Q2:
[I already have the contact form coded but I am trying to create a box that will display what is typed and submitted in the comments box for the form can anyone assist me please?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEGV0.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [**`<frameset>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) is deprecated, and not supported in HTML 5. I **strongly** advise against using it. What exactly are you trying to achieve by using framesets? 'partials'? Could you please update your question to clearly indicate **exactly** what you're trying to do? Regardless of what you're trying to do, there's definitely a better approach to your problem :)

Comment: im using it to create a header, a main body and two vertical frames that are just colored to add design to my site, this is a basic html class i am in and don't know a ton of css or html

Comment: While it would generally be best to use a server-side language for dynamic 'included' content, you can also make use of [**HTML imports**](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/), which don't require any server-side code :)

Comment: **frameset**, **frame**, and **noframes** elements are not supported in HTML5.

Comment: This is for a class so it has to be coded server sided. We haven't learned any javascript so i must just be SOL

Comment: I have updated the post with another question if anyone is able to assist